# Create a task programmatically in RingCentral

Tags: powershell, ringcentral, glip

I can create a post to Glip with the following code:

```
$AddPostHeader  =  @{'Content-Type'  =  'application/json';'Authorization'='Bearer ' + $token}
    $AddPostURL = 'https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/glip/chats/' + $selectedGroup + '/posts'
    $AddPostBody = @{'type' = 'TextMessage'; 'text' = 'This post was written from Powershell'}
    $AddPostBody = ConvertTo-Json $AddPostBody

    $NewPost = Invoke-RestMethod -h $AddPostHeader -Body $AddPostBody $AddPostURL -Method 'POST'
    $AddPostURL
    $NewPost
```

But how can I create a Task?

This says I can: https://medium.com/ringcentral-developers/automating-team-productivity-with-glip-748a05aa32e9

I have referenced https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference without any luck?  Is there an option 'type' for a post?

Answer (score 0):

The API References now has a set of RingCentral Tasks APIs. The Create Tasks API is here:

- https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Tasks/createTask

A quick example of using this API using HTTP is as follows:

Required fields:

- `chatId` (path)
- `subject` (body) Task name
- `assignees` (body) `personId` for assignee

Example Request:

```
POST https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/glip/chats/{chatId}/tasks
Authorization: Bearer <myToken>
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "subject": "My New Task",
  "assignees": [{"id":"123"}]
}
```